# headerActions Show in App, but they do not Show inside Community Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, lightning-apps

I am having issues trying to display headerActions in a component imported inside a community page. In the Salesforce App for development they show, but when imported they don't.

In Salesforce App for development:
[image: In Salesforce App for development]

In the community page:
[image: In the community page]

This is the datatable in the component:

```
        <!--    Data Table  -->
        <div style="height: calc(100vh - 340px);">
            <lightning:datatable class="slds-table"
                                 aura:id="relatedRecords" 
                                 data="{! v.data }"
                                 columns="{! v.columns }"
                                 keyField="Id" 
                                 enableInfiniteLoading="{!v.enableInfiniteLoading}"
                                 onloadmore="{! c.loadMoreData }"
                                 hideTableHeader="false" 
                                 resizeColumnDisabled="true"
                                 hideCheckboxColumn="true" 
                                 loadMoreOffset="{! v.loadMoreOffset }"
                                 onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }"
                                 onheaderaction="{! c.handleHeaderAction }" />
        </div>
```

This is how I am defining the column attributes and properties inside the init function in the Javascript controller:

```
init : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    
    //  Define content for Rows Actions
    const actions = [
        { label: 'Open', name: 'open', iconName: 'utility:open' },
    ];
        
        
     // Define header actions
     const headerActions = [
        { label: 'All', checked: true, name:'all' },
        { label: 'Published', checked: false, name:'show_published' }
    ];
    
    
    //  Define Table header, and Rows data
    cmp.set('v.columns', [
        {label: 'User', fieldName: 'user', type:'text', hideDefaultActions: true, actions: headerActions},
        {label: 'Contact', fieldName: 'contact', type:'text', hideDefaultActions: true, actions: headerActions},
        {label: 'Date', fieldName: 'timestamp', type:'date', typeAttributes:{ year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "2-digit", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit"}, hideDefaultActions: true, actions: headerActions},
        {label: 'Type', fieldName: 'type', type:"text", hideDefaultActions: true, actions: headerActions},
        { type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions } }
    ]);
    
    
    // Dummy table data
    cmp.set("v.data", [
        {'user':'User 1','contact': 'Contact 1','type': 'Type 1', 'timestamp': '2013-08-01 12:00:00'},
        {'user':'User 2','contact': 'Contact 2','type': 'Type 2', 'timestamp': '2013-08-01 12:00:00'},
        {'user':'User n','contact': 'Contact n','type': 'Type n', 'timestamp': '2013-08-01 12:00:00'},
    ]);
    
},
```

Comment: Please add the minimal required code so that community can have a look on issue.

Comment: @sanketkumar, thank you for your willingness to help. I just added the code I am using to define the table properties, and the table definition.